# How to extract coordinates from an R/terra SpatVector object?

Tags: r, terra

I have some `SpatVector` objects from which I would like to get the point coordinates back out. From the documentation and examples, it looks like `as.data.frame` should do the job...

```
sq = terra::vect(cbind(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)), type = "points", crs = "local")
terra::as.data.frame(sq)
```

... but I am only getting empty values.

```
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

What is the correct way to get the matrix/data.frame of coordinates in this situation?

Comment: is `terra::geom(sq)` what you need?

Comment: Yes - please add that as an answer so I can accept it. I was not aware that the `geom` function also returned the coordinates - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`terra::geom()` returns a matrix with i.a. coordinate columns which you can convert to a data frame as follows (using your example data **sq**):

```
sq |> geom() |> as.data.frame()
```

```
  geom part x y hole
1    1    1 0 0    0
2    2    1 1 0    0
3    3    1 1 1    0
4    4    1 0 1    0
5    5    1 0 0    0
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the coordinates of a SpatVector you can use `crds` or `geom`

```
library(terra)
sq = terra::vect(cbind(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)), type = "points", crs = "local")

crds(sq)
#     x y
#[1,] 0 0
#[2,] 1 0
#[3,] 1 1
#[4,] 0 1
#[5,] 0 0

geom(sq)
#     geom part x y hole
#[1,]    1    1 0 0    0
#[2,]    2    1 1 0    0
#[3,]    3    1 1 1    0
#[4,]    4    1 0 1    0
#[5,]    5    1 0 0    0

geom(sq, wkt=TRUE)
#[1] "POINT (0 0)" "POINT (1 0)" "POINT (1 1)" "POINT (0 1)" "POINT (0 0)"
```

If you also want the attributes (but in this example there are none) you can use `as.data.frame` with an appropriate value for the "geom" argument.

```
as.data.frame(sq, geom="XY")
#  x y
#1 0 0
#2 1 0
#3 1 1
#4 0 1
#5 0 0

as.data.frame(sq, geom="WKT")
#     geometry
#1 POINT (0 0)
#2 POINT (1 0)
#3 POINT (1 1)
#4 POINT (0 1)
#5 POINT (0 0)
```